# Why does Philip use Kate's failure to read his article as a reason to discuss the situation with her?

Tags: dont-look-up

Prof. Mindy and Philip discussed appearing on ‘The Daily Rip’ before their
article’s publication. Philip was excited about the show and its hosts, Brie and
Jack. He shared his past experience of being cut for time, which still hurt him.
He also mentioned that his wife was a fan of the show. Then, he started a
conversation with Kate:

> Philip: Okay, **can you just tell me what this is all about? Okay?
> 'Cause you haven't read my article** on Conlon getting hard in the art class.
> Now Adul Grelio has come down from his mountaintop for your thing.
> You won't even give me a lousy pronoun? Come on.

Why does Philip use Kate's failure to read his article as a reason to discuss the situation with her?